# Check continuity in streamflow records in R

Tags: r, date, time

I want to check if there is a discontinuity in years in the records of my streamflow data. I create a loop to select the stations with higher number of 30 years of records and I want to also select only the ones with continued data (this means continuity in years: 1998,1999,2000,20001, but not a change from 1998 to 2000.

How can I make a loop to select continuity in the years or even months? At the moment this is my code working as I expected:

```
Daily_Streamflow <- Daily_Streamflow %>% mutate(month = month(Date))
Daily_Streamflow <- Daily_Streamflow %>% mutate(month = month(Date))

 if (length(unique(Daily_Streamflow$year)) > 30) 
  {
    (name <- paste("DSF", siteNumber[i], sep = "_"))
    (name2 <- paste("Site_Info", siteNumber[i], sep = "_"))
    assign(name, value = Daily_Streamflow)
    assign(name2, value = siteINFO)
    #print(name)
  
  }
```

How can I add the continuity condition in the if?

**My desire output is to save as data frames in R only the data records of streamflow gages with a period of records higher than 30 years (length(unique(Daily_Streamflow$year)) > 30) and I want to add the condition that only when there is no a discontinuity in the records of more than 3 months. What I am missing is the second condition of continuity**

Comment: Please add a small example along with expected output so that it is easier for others to help you.

Comment: I tried to add my desire output in bold font at the end of the question